# Объясните логику куска кода на Java

Tags: java, тернарный-оператор

```
int x = 5;
System.out.println(x > 2 ? x < 4 ? 10 : 8 : 7);
```

Проходил один тест, столкнулся с вот такой вот задачей(нужно было ответить, что получится в итоге) Скопировал код, запустил - выдало 8. Сижу и не могу понять логики кода.

Comment: ключевые слова: тернарный оператор. Тут используется дважды

Comment: все станет понятней, если расставить скобки явно `x > 2 ? (x < 4 ? 10 : 8) : 7`

Comment: Немного дополню комментарии выше. В тернарной операции знак `?` ищет ближайший к нему `:` и они объединяются в одну операцию. Внутренний `?` будет искать свой ближайший оператор первее в порядке очереди, поэтому сначала он получит свою логику `(x < 4 ? 10 : 8)` как единая операция, а потом внешний получит свою логику `x > 2 ? (x < 4 ? 10 : 8) : 7`.

Answer (score 0):

В данной строке кода используются 2 тернарных оператора(выражение ? true : false).
Если расставить скобки, то все становиться понятно:

```
(x > 2 ? (x < 4 ? 10 : 8) : 7)
```